# PDO show all exceptions except for 'table not found'

Tags: php, exception, pdo

I'm working on my converter script and I need to be able to see errors like with foreign keys or duplicate primary key values. But I want to be able to hide the 'table not found' errors.

If I set errors on silent, it shows no errors. If I put it on exception, it shows all errors (when it shouldn't show table not found errors).

Any way of managing this without string contains or something like that?

Comment: You'd have to wrap your code in a try catch, then in the catch check the message for the error you're looking for. If it matches, continue, if it doesn't re-throw the exception.

Comment: If there's no other option I'll just do this.